# Validating a MUI Datepicker with YUP in a react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form, yup

I have a date picker that needs to validate the following scenarios:

1. It is a required field and cannot be left blank
2. The date must be later `minDate` (21 days from today )
3. The date must be earlier than six months from `minDate`

The validation schema I came up with looks as follows, which, works unexpectedly.

```
import * as yup from 'yup'
import { addDays, addMonths, format} from 'date-fns'

const today = Date.now()
const minDate = addDays(today, 21)
const maxDate = addMonths(minDate, 6)

const schema = yup.object().shape({
 Date: yup
    .date()
    .min(minDate, `Date must be after ${format(minDate,'MM/dd/yyyy')}`)
    .max(maxDate, `Date must be before ${format(maxDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy') }`)
    .typeError("Date is required") 
})
```

What do I mean by it works unexpectedly

1. When you click the submit button for the first time, the
   `typeError()` message is display.(Expected behavior)
2. Then, if you selected a date from by clicking on the calendar icon,
   the date gets displayed and the error disappear. (Expected behavior)
3. Finally, if I manually clear the selected day the `min()` error
   message gets displayed. **(make sense but is not what I expected)**

It makes sense because, as the date gets transformed with every keystroke, the `min()` the error message is triggered, but eventually, the date is not valid and its value becomes `null`.

**Question:** So, at this point should the typeError() message be displayed?

**Date picker code**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Controller } from 'react-hook-form'
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField'
import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns'
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider'
import { DesktopDatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DesktopDatePicker'
import { addDays, addMonths, format, isValid } from 'date-fns'
const Calendar = ({ control, name, label, error, helperText, ...rest }) => {
  const today = Date.now()
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <Controller
        name={name}
        control={control}
        render={({ field }) => (
          <DesktopDatePicker
            label={label}
            value={value}
            minDate={addDays(today, 21)}
            maxDate={addMonths(addDays(today, 21), 6)}
            onChange={(newValue) => {
              if (isValid(newValue))
              {
                field.onChange(format(newValue, 'MM/dd/yyyy'))
                setValue(newValue)
              } else
              {
                setValue(newValue)
              }
            }}
            renderInput={(params) =>
              <TextField
                margin='normal'
                helperText={helperText}
                {...params}
                {...rest}
                error={error}
              />
            }
          />
        )}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  )
}

export default Calendar
```

> [CHECK WORKING EXAMPLE >](https://codesandbox.io/s/calendar-xewjkg?file=/src/schema.js)